# Mains And Battery Monitor Using Delay on And Delay off

Tags: arduino-uno

I am very new to Arduino. In fact I am entirely new to embedded system. I have been using other platforms for my experiments specifically PICs.

I just moved to Arduino for more easier coding but I am hooked somewhere.

Here is the constraints:

In the code I will post below;

1. When MAINS is present and is within usable range, both MAINS_OK & ENABLE Pins will go HIGH after 3sec delay(non-blocking).
2. When MAINS is BAD, MAINS_OK Pin will go LOW immediately while ENABLE Pin will wait for 3sec before going LOW.
3. If MAINS is recovered and is within usable range again, the sequence described in "1." must be followed an so on.

I have tried in so many ways, it is not working as expected. Only the blinking of the SYSTEM LED is working fine.

```
// constants won't change. Used here to
// set pin numbers:
const int enablePin     = 7;      // the number of the Function Pins
const int lvdPin        = 6;
const int sysledPin    = 5;
const int mainsokPin   = 4;


// Variables will change:
int mainsPin = A0;
int batteryPin = A2;
int MAINS;
int BATT;
int ENABLE = LOW;
int LVD = LOW;
int SYS_LED = LOW;
int MAINS_OK = LOW; // State used to set the Function Pins

long previousMillis1 = 0;
long previousMillis2 = 0;// will store last time PIN was updated
long previousMillis3 = 0;
long previousMillis4 = 0;
long previousMillis5 = 0;


long ENABLE_ON        = 3000;
long ENABLE_OFF       = 3000;
long LVD_ON           = 3000;
long LVD_OFF          = 3000;
long MAINS_DELAY_ON   = 3000;
long MAINS_DELAY_OFF  = 0;
long SYS_LED_ON       = 1000;
long SYS_LED_OFF      = 1000; //Duration of the delay time (milliseconds)

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ENABLE, OUTPUT);  // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(LVD, OUTPUT);     // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(SYS_LED, OUTPUT); // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(MAINS_OK, OUTPUT); // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(A0, INPUT); //set pin as Analog nput
  pinMode(A1, INPUT); //set pin as Analog nput
}
void loop()
{
  unsigned long currentMillis1 = millis();
  unsigned long currentMillis2 = millis();
  unsigned long currentMillis3 = millis();
  unsigned long currentMillis4 = millis();



  if ((SYS_LED == LOW) && (currentMillis1 - previousMillis1 >= SYS_LED_OFF))
  {
    SYS_LED = HIGH;  // Turn it off
    previousMillis1 = currentMillis1;  // Remember the time
    digitalWrite(sysledPin, SYS_LED);  // Update the actual SYS_LED
  }
  if ((SYS_LED == HIGH) && (currentMillis1 - previousMillis1 >= SYS_LED_ON))
  {
    SYS_LED = LOW;  // turn it on
    previousMillis1 = currentMillis1;   // Remember the time
    digitalWrite(sysledPin, SYS_LED);    // Update the actual SYS_LED
  }

  MAINS = analogRead(mainsPin);

  //========================= MAINS OK =======================================
  /* If MAINS supply is ok, the MAINS_OK and ENABLE Pins will wait for 3sec
      before going high. Both Pins will go high at the same time.
  */

  if (MAINS >= 84 && MAINS <= 177) // >=0.410V && <=0.864V >=140V && <=250V
    if ((MAINS_OK == LOW) && (currentMillis2 - previousMillis2 >= MAINS_DELAY_ON))
    {
      MAINS_OK = HIGH;  // Turn MAINS_OK on with 3sec delay
      previousMillis2 = currentMillis2;  // Remember the time
      digitalWrite(mainsokPin, MAINS_OK);  // Update the actual MAINS_OK
    }
  if (MAINS >= 84 && MAINS <= 177) // >=0.410V && <=0.864V >=140V && <=250V
    if ((ENABLE == LOW) && (currentMillis3 - previousMillis3 >= ENABLE_ON))
    {
      ENABLE = HIGH;    //Turn ENABLE ON with 3sec delay
      previousMillis3 = currentMillis3;  // Remember the time
      digitalWrite(enablePin, ENABLE);  // Update the actual MAINS_OK
    }

  //=================== MAINS NOT PRESENT or IT IS LOW/HIGH VOLTAGE ====================
  /* As soon as MAINS is lost, whether it enters low voltage or high voltage,
     the PINs MAINS_OK will go LOW imedatly without delay while ENABLE will wait for
     3sec before going LOW. Then If MAINS is restored OK, the initial delay sequence
     must be followed.
  */
  if (MAINS <= 53 || MAINS >= 258) // <= 0.260V || >=1.26V// Below <= 120V and >= 276V
    if ((MAINS_OK == HIGH) && (currentMillis2 - previousMillis2 >= MAINS_DELAY_OFF))
    {
      MAINS_OK = LOW;  // Turn MAINS_OK off after 0sec delay
      previousMillis2 = currentMillis2;  // Remember the time
      digitalWrite(mainsokPin, MAINS_OK);  // Update the actual MAINS_OK
    }
  if (MAINS <= 53 || MAINS >= 258) // <= 0.260V || >=1.26V// Below <= 120V and >= 276V
    if ((ENABLE == HIGH) && (currentMillis3 - previousMillis3 >= ENABLE_OFF))
    {
      ENABLE = LOW;    //Turn ENABLE off aftar 3sec delay
      previousMillis3 = currentMillis3;  // Remember the time
      digitalWrite(enablePin, ENABLE);  // Update the actual ENABLE
    }


  BATT = analogRead(batteryPin);

  //============================ BATTERYERY SETTINGS ==============================
  /* If Battery is below 21V LVD Pin go HIGH with 3sec delay
      When it goes high, it remains high the Batter goes up to 27.6V
      LVD will then go LOW ahter 3sec delay
  */
  if (BATT <= 391) //(1.91V) 21V         // BATTERY Low
    if ((LVD == LOW) && (currentMillis4 - previousMillis4 >= LVD_ON))
    {
      LVD = HIGH; //Turn LVD on with 3sec delay
      previousMillis4 = currentMillis4;  // Remember the time
      digitalWrite(lvdPin, LVD);  // Update the actual LVD
    }

  if (BATT >= 512) // (2.50V)  27.6V         // BATTERY low Recovery
    if ((LVD == HIGH) && (currentMillis4 - previousMillis4 >= LVD_OFF))
    {
      LVD = LOW; // turn LVD off after 3sec delay
      previousMillis4 = currentMillis4;  // Remember the time
      digitalWrite(lvdPin, LVD);  // Update the actual LVD
    }
}
```

Please What can I add or remove from this code for it to work properly?

Thanks.

Comment: `When MAINS is OK` ... i think that you would get undesired behavior with that test because it is true every time you check the value .... you probably want `When MAINS becomes OK`  ... that happens only once at transitions between OK and NOT-OK

Comment: When MAINS is OK means when mains is within usable range but "MAINS_OK" is a digital output pin.

Comment: you are misunderstanding my comment ... if you test for MAINS is OK then you will set the 3 second timer over and over ... you have to test for the transition between NOT-OK and OK

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of problems with your code. To start, most/all of this code is wrong:

```
  pinMode(ENABLE, OUTPUT);  // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(LVD, OUTPUT);     // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(SYS_LED, OUTPUT); // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(MAINS_OK, OUTPUT); // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(A0, INPUT); //set pin as Analog nput
  pinMode(A1, INPUT); //set pin as Analog nput
```

Those lines should be setting various pins to their desired input/output state. However, you are using the variables you declared to hold their bool status, not their pin numbers.

The variables you are using are declared like this:

```
int ENABLE = LOW;
int LVD = LOW;
int SYS_LED = LOW;
int MAINS_OK = LOW; // State used to set the Function Pins
```

Those are not pin numbers, those are variables that hold boolean values.

This line, for example:

```
pinMode(MAINS_OK, OUTPUT); // set the digital pin as output:
```

Should almost certainly read

```
pinMode(mainsokPin, OUTPUT); // set the digital pin as output:
```

Instead.

Same goes for `enablePin`, `lvdPin`, and `sysledPin`

The two lines

```
pinMode(A0, INPUT); //set pin as Analog nput
pinMode(A1, INPUT); //set pin as Analog nput
```

Should probably read

```
pinMode(mainsPin, INPUT); //set pin as Analog nput
pinMode(batteryPin, INPUT); //set pin as Analog nput
```

Since you define the variables `mainsPin` and `batteryPin`.

Comment: Thanks Duncan! I will go now and edit the code according to you advise.